# Prevent span in paragraph from wrapping

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have quote symbols placed in `span` elements which are children of a `p` element. Visually, different quote styles can be applied which need slightly different CSS. For reasons resulting from the backend solution I need the quotes to be placed inside the HTML, I cannot put them in CSS.

Depending on the window width there are some cases where the last `.quot--qr` breaks to the next line.

How can I make `.quot--qr` behave so that it does not break to the next line?

Fiddle here, you can see the problem when the result panel is approx. 245px wide: http://jsfiddle.net/jqnyxkrg/

**Screenshot of problem**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="quot--wrapper">

  <p class="quot--text">
    <span class="quot--ql quot--style-a">„</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit consectetuer adipiscing elit adipiscing elit lorem.
    <span class="quot--qr quot--style-a">“</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.quot--text {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0px;

  font-family: "Arial","Helvetica",sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 31px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.quot--ql,
.quot--qr {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  font-family: "Arial","Helvetica",sans-serif;
}

/* these values are different for each possible "quot style" */
.quot--ql.quot--style-a, 
.quot--qr.quot--style-a {
  font-size: 76px;
}

.quot--ql.quot--style-a {
  top: -11px;
}

.quot--qr.quot--style-a {
  top: 38px;
}
```

Comment: If you could alter html code you could remove white space between last `.` and `<span>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jqnyxkrg/1/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't take care of that and for now it seems to work. You should add an answer so I can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

i made you two fiddles:

1st with absolute positioning of both elements, because i didnt undertstand the question ;-)
http://jsfiddle.net/jqnyxkrg/2/

```
.quot--text {   
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 1.5em; 
}
.quot--ql.quot--style-a, 
.quot--qr.quot--style-a {
  font-size: 76px;
  position:absolute;
}    
.quot--ql.quot--style-a {
  top: -11px;
  left:0;
}    
.quot--qr.quot--style-a {
  bottom: -11px;
  right:0;
}
```

the 2nd one does what you need, but in some content/width combinations can overlay the last letters of the text.
http://jsfiddle.net/jqnyxkrg/3/

```
.quot--qr.quot--style-a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  right:0;
}
```

maybe your solution can be to add a no breaking space between the last letter and the span, but this can cause other problems.